# How do i edit multible rows in mysql based on a set of criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a mysqlp table which contains a set of data as in the sample excel file. We need a query that will copy the product name into the customer field where customer = Luxury. We used the below query to start editing one by one but there are thousands of records.

```
SET customer = 'TAVERNAKI' WHERE product = 'TAVERNAKI' AND customer = 'LUXURY';
```

So we are going about copying and pasting the query and replacing the product name each time.  Does anyone have an idea for a mass edit of all records?

Sample file in the link here
[1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sgtwNobMU5mKCLuxDLqhpEivEekI0l4R/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107367920163394089177&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
UPDATE table SET customer=product WHERE customer='Luxury'
```

Comment: Works like a charm. So simple and so helpful. 1 mil thanks Mr. Lelio Faieta!